# Div style according to the place of CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #aDiv{
            width:300px;
            height:100px;
            background-color:blue;
        }
    </style>
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="aDiv"></div>
</body>
```

If I launch the html in the above form, the blue rectangle is displayed. 
If I saved the style in a css file (respectively ***style.css***) the rectangle is not displayed. This behaviour is valid for all the browsers I tried (Firefox, IE, Chrome). How to solve this problem ?

Comment: add like this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

Comment: @Thinker How would that help? It's HTML5, `type="text/css"` isn't required.

Comment: What's `<!--link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"-->`? And post the contents of style.css and the HTML you use to link to it.

Comment: Are you un-commenting your `link` element when you try this? Removing `!--` and `--` at the end?

Comment: CCS file: #aDiv{
 width:300px;
 height:l00px;
 background-color:blue;
}

Comment: @EbticBobo Add extra information as an edit, not a comment. Also un-comment your `link` tag, and ensure the CSS file is in the same directory as the HTML file. Otherwise we cannot help with the given information, and this question will be closed.

Comment: If I remove the <style>...</style> and I uncomment the <link....> section, (ie - I load style.css) the rectangle is not displayed. CSS file is in the same folder.,

Comment: And the html to link to style.css:<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="aDiv"></div>
 </body> 
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you posted in the comments is the actualy contents of your style.css file, your problem is simple to solve - you have a typo:

```
#aDiv { width:300px; height:l00px; background-color:blue; }
```

It should be this (take a look at the height value - you had a lower-case L in there in place of a 1):

```
#aDiv { width:300px; height:100px; background-color:blue; }
```

This results in an element of `height: 0` to render, which you won't be able to see.

When testing this, remember to un-comment the link line in your html head.

Comment: That appears to be the case, just note this question would need to be closed as a typographical error.